# How to properly use gulp-vulcanize

Tags: javascript, build, gulp, vulcanize

I can't use gulp-vulcanize in my side project.
I've followed the example but nothing seems to happen, there are also no errors in the console.

Here is my folder structure:

build/ 
  - html/ 
  - css/ 
  - js/ 
source/ 
  - html/ 
  - css/ 
  - js/ 
bower.json 
gulpfile.coffee 
gulpfile.js 
package.json

Here is the gulp task I'm using

```
gulp.task 'vulcanize',
  ->
    gulp.src 'index.html'
      .pipe plumber()
      .pipe vulcanize {
        abspath: ''
        excludes: []
        stripExcludes: false
      }
      .pipe gulp.dest 'vulcanized'
```

I'm using the following for vulcanizing my html files:

- gulp - 3.9.0
- gulp-vulcanize - 6.1.0
- gul-crisper - 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

There is no `index.html` file in the same directory as your `gulpfile`. So nothing can happen. Give it the proper path :

```
gulp.task 'vulcanize', ->
    gulp.src 'build/html/index.html'
        .pipe vulcanize()
        .pipe gulp.dest 'vulcanized'
```

Don't pass any option to vulcanuze(), as you're just passing its defaults, so it's useless.

BTW, Gulp accepts coffee files, you don't have to compile your `gulpfile.coffee` into `gulpfile.js`. Just go :

```
npm install -g coffee-script

gulp

> using gulpfile.coffee
```

Comment: I've changed the gulp.src to be 'build/html/index.html' and also removed the options, but I still get the same result

Comment: Its working now, the issue is about the paths of the files being imported by index.html, thanks for the help and tip